# Changing GLSL version to be compatible with GL3

Tags: java, glsl

I am getting this error when trying to run the DesktopLauncher for my first game I am attempting to make:

```
Fragment shader failed to compile with the following errors:
ERROR: error(#272) Implicit version number 110 not supported by GL3 forward compatible context
ERROR: error(#273) 1 compilation errors.  No code generated


at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.createDefaultShader(SpriteBatch.java:157)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.<init>(SpriteBatch.java:120)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.<init>(SpriteBatch.java:73)
at com.cosmicluck.mygame.GameScreen.<init>(GameScreen.java:22)
at com.cosmicluck.mygame.MyGame.create(MyGame.java:12)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:147)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
```

Now when I looked around to try and find out what I was doing wrong, I came across a solution that said to specify the version of GLSL using:

```
#version 150
```

But my problem is I don't know where to put that, I was told to put that with my shader but I don't have a shader as far as I can tell. Either way here's my code:

DesktopLauncher:

```
package com.cosmicluck.mygame.desktop;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
import com.cosmicluck.mygame.MyGame;

public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        new LwjglApplication(new MyGame(), config);
        config.title = "Test";
        config.resizable = true;
    }
}
```

MyGame class (creates game screen):

```
package com.cosmicluck.mygame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;

public class MyGame extends Game {

    public GameScreen game_screen;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        Assets.load();
        game_screen = new GameScreen(this);
        setScreen(game_screen);
    }
}
```

GameScreen class:

```
package com.cosmicluck.mygame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL30;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram;

public class GameScreen implements Screen{

MyGame game;
OrthographicCamera camera;
SpriteBatch batch;

public GameScreen(MyGame game){
    this.game = game;
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(true, 1920, 1080);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
}

@Override
public void show() {
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.95F, 0.95F, 0.95F, 0.95F);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(Assets.sprite_background, 0, 0);
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}

@Override
public void hide() {
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}
}
```

Again any information that could be used to help me would be great! Thank you for taking the time to look at this!

Answer (score 1):

> I don't have a shader as far as I can tell.

You may not directly. But whatever library `com.badlogic.gdx.g2d.SpriteBatch` comes from, *it* creates a shader. And that shader uses GLSL 1.10.

Personally, I would ditch any library that doesn't even use a `#version` declaration in its GLSL shader. That would be an indication of gross ignorance and/or incompetence on the part of the developers. There are plenty of game frameworks out there to use, so there's no need to use a *crappy* one.

However, if you insist on using this tool, then you *cannot* create a core profile OpenGL context. So your LWJGL initialization code needs to remove those attribute bits (and you can't use any GL version higher than 2.1, unless you don't want your code to run on MacOSX). You didn't show that initialization code, so you'll have to work it out for yourself.